# Apply a filter in aggregation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

Let's say that I have the following `pd.DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'number': [1, 1, 1, 2],  'q':[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 1], 'letter': ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'alpha']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   number   q   letter
0   1      NaN   alpha
1   1      2.0   beta
2   1      NaN   gamma
3   2      1.0   alpha
```

What I want to do is to aggregate by number and create a list with all the letters and apply a filter based on the value of the `q`.

If I do this:

`df.groupby('number').agg({"letter": lambda w: list(w) })` will yield:

```
    letter
number  
1   [alpha, beta, gamma]
2   [alpha]
```

But I want to include only the the columns such that the corresponding `q` value is not `NaN`, i.e.

```
  number    letter
0   1       [beta]
1   2       [alpha]
```

**Edit**: I would appreciate a more generic solution (not just if we have `NaN` values), but if we want to specify the value of `q` as a threshold of what is going to be included or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think to need [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df1 = df.dropna().groupby('number').agg({"letter": lambda w: list(w)})
```

If want specify column for remove missing values:

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['q']).groupby('number').agg({"letter": lambda w: list(w)})
print (df1)
         letter
number         
1        [beta]
2       [alpha]
```

EDIT:

You can filter also by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("q > 0").groupby('number').agg({"letter": lambda w: list(w)})
```

Or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['q'] > 0].groupby('number').agg({"letter": lambda w: list(w)})

df1 = df[df['q'].notnull()].groupby('number').agg({"letter": lambda w: list(w)})
```

EDIT1:

Filtering is possible also in function, for avoid lost non matched groups:

```
def f(x):
    return x.loc[x['q'] > 1, 'letter'].tolist()

df2 = df.groupby('number').apply(f).reset_index(name='val')
print (df2)
   number     val
0       1  [beta]
1       2      []

df1 = df[df['q'] > 1].groupby('number').agg({"letter": lambda w: list(w)})
print (df1)
        letter
number        
1       [beta]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would need something more general. For example if the value of `q` is greater than a specified number. Great, thanks!